# Loop through list of file paths to send as input to script

Tags: bash

```
#Create list of files with a ext
#Loop through list of flies in list.txt and pass to myscript
    find /directory -name "*.gz" > list.txt
    for f in `cat list.txt`
    do
        $myscript -S \
            --g ${f} \
            --s ${filename2} \
            --og ${outfile}_${f} \
            --os ${outfile}_${f}.sample
   done;
```

I get an error saying the input (file path) is an "Unknown parameter" and it seems to put an "_" in front of it. Am I setting the variable incorrectly?. Error is with --g arg. $Myscript is path to program. No spaces in list of files and each file on a line starting with /home/directory/...

Comment: Does the filename have spaces, and what is `$myscript`? need more information...

Comment: No spaces just a list and myscript points to the hard path of my program where the file is being passed to

Comment: please run your code thru http://shellcheck.net and be sure to Include `#!/bin/bash` as the top line of your code. Then fix all errors flagged. If that doesn't fix your problem, then update your Q with the corrected code. Sample inputs and expected outputs would also be nice. Good luck.

Comment: Run the script with trace on to see the expansions, something like `bash -x script-name`.  Where is the message "Unknown parameter" coming from?  Is it from `$myscript`?